# Using a RewriteRule to clean my URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My main goal here is to change what users see when they visit my site.

As of now, if I want to navigate my site, it's done as so:

http://ieztech.net/~aeterna/index.php?page=home or http://ieztech.net/~aeterna/index.php?page=contact-us

What I'm trying to accomplish is, when I send a user to my contact page, I want them to be able to go to `http://ieztech.net/~aeterna/contact-us/` but actually display what is located at `http://ieztech.net/~aeterna/index.php?page=contact-us`.

I have tried a lot of variations of `RewriteRule` but I can't seem to figure this out.

Here is what I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I have also tried (which I found [here](http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls)):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is there something else I'm missing, or is what I'm trying just not correct?

Comment: Your last rule works for me. What goes wrong when you try it? Anything in your server error logs?

Comment: @showdev I can still navigate the site using index.php?page=contact-us, but if I was to go to /contact-us/ it displays a 404. The only thing in my error log is: `[Fri May 30 17:27:56 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /home/aeterna/public_html/home, referer: /~aeterna/home/`

Comment: Why is it trying to go to "home" if you're going to `/contact-us/`?

Comment: @JonLin I was going to "home" - just using `contact-us` as an example. I didn't catch that when posting the log, sorry.

@showdev I've updated my post with a link to my site, which currently echos `$page`.

Comment: If you want everything to get dumped into your index.php by way of $page var, then I suggest something like #3 except with `^(.*)$` (no slash).

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles If I remove the slash, then I get a 404 error on all pages I visit, including the index.

Comment: For `contact-us/`, I get `403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /home/aeterna/public_html/index.php on this server.` Does that path look correct?

Comment: That is correct, but it shouldn't be throwing a 403 error. There is nothing in the logs other than `[Fri May 30 17:42:49 2014] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /home/aeterna/public_html/contact-us`

Comment: This is what I've been using for many years now: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.cgi?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]` along with several conditions.

Comment: `RewriteBase` may be a factor.

Comment: I would try adding `RewriteBase /~aeterna` and see what that does.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles The .htaccess file is located in /home/aeterna/public_html/ which is /~aeterna/ - is this an issue?

Comment: Another thing you can do is change [L] to [R] temporarily to see what mod rewrite is doing to the URL.

Comment: After changing it to [R], it seems `http://192.185.9.14/~aeterna/contact-us/` changes to `http://192.185.9.14/index.php?page=contact-us/`. I changed the `RewriteBase` to `RewriteBase /~aeterna/` and it triggers a redirect loop: http://192.185.9.14/~aeterna/contact-us/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
RewriteBase /~aeterna
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Add this condition to prevent rewriting particular files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|css|js)
```

Comment: After adding your edit, that is fixed, thanks! What about the addition of a trailing slash? `http://192.185.9.14/~aeterna/twitch-raffle/` => `http://192.185.9.14/~aeterna/index.php?page=twitch-raffle/` I have tried stripping slashes within my code but it seems like that isn't removing it.

Comment: Perfect! It seems as though my final problem, is that when I visit `http://192.185.9.14/~aeterna/`, I would like it to display `http://192.185.9.14/~aeterna/index.php?page=home` by default. I have tried forcing the `$page` variable to `home` if it is not set, but it's not budging! I am trying this:

    `$page = $_GET['page'];`
    
    `if (!isset($page)) {`
     `$page = 'home';`
    `}`
    
    `die('Page: "' . $page . '"');`

You can try here: http://192.185.9.14/~aeterna/

Comment: That's a different topic, ask about it in a new question and post your PHP code.

Comment: It seems as though it was just a design flaw I hadn't thought out. Thank you for your help :)